# Get TEMP folder

Tags: inno-setup, temp

How do I get the path to the Temp folder from inside an InnoSetup Pascal script? Not the folder that the setup uses as it its temporary folder (which can be accessed using `{tmp}`), but the actual user's Temp folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `TEMP` environment variable using the `{%TEMP}` constant.

See [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) for details and a list of all constants.