# Creating A Folder In the Temp Folder

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to create a folder within the temp folder that doesn't have a random name.
Here is how I was trying to create the folder within the temp folder.

```
if not DirExists(ExpandConstant('{%tmp}\Utilities\SDK')) then
    CreateDir(ExpandConstant('{%tmp}\Utilities\SDK'));
    Log('Temp\Utilities\SDK Folder Has Been Created.');
```

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318305/get-temp-folder) thread, but even with the `%`, unfortunately, it still doesn't create the folder.
The script compiles and runs as expected, however the folder doesn't create even though it says it has in the log file,
 I understand that the log file will say that because its told too, however, if the folder was unable to be created, wouldnt it crash? or return a false if an if statement was present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**With `CreateDir()` You must create dirs one after the other and not a dir structure at once.**

```
if not DirExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Utilities')) then
  CreateDir(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Utilities'));
if not DirExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Utilities\SDK')) then
  CreateDir(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Utilities\SDK'));

if DirExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Utilities\SDK')) then
   Log('Temp\Utilities\SDK Folder Has Been Created.') else
   Log('Temp\Utilities\SDK Folder ERROR : NOT Created.');
```

**Inno Setup has a function to create a dir structure at once**
`function ForceDirectories(Dir: string): Boolean;`

**Example:**

```
if not DirExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Utilities\SDK')) then
   ForceDirectories(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Utilities\SDK'));
```

**Also keep in mind :**

- {tmp} all is related to the Inno Setup Temp folder **is-XXXXX.tmp**
  C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\is-XXXXX.tmp
- {%temp} is the users Temp folder
  C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the Windows Temp and not the `tmp` from InnoSetup

> {tmp}: 
>   Temporary directory used by Setup or Uninstall. This is not the value of the user's TEMP environment variable. It is a subdirectory of the user's temporary directory which is created by Setup or Uninstall at startup (with a name like "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\IS-xxxxx.tmp"). **All files and subdirectories in this directory are deleted when Setup or Uninstall exits.** During Setup, this is primarily useful for extracting files that are to be executed in the [Run] section but aren't needed after the installation.

So I think you want to do somethink like this:

```
if not DirExists(ExpandConstant('{%temp}\Utilities\SDK')) then
   CreateDir(ExpandConstant('{%temp}\Utilities\SDK'));
   Log('Temp\Utilities\SDK Folder Has Been Created.');
```